# Vertical menu with a full width horizontal dropdown

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, dropdown

So basically this is my situation:

[image]

MENU has a 25% width, MENU DROPDOWN - 75%, but this width relates to MENU's 25%.
If I create a container thats 100% width and catches both menu and menu dropdown, I won't be able to click on slider behind, since my container is overlapping it.

What solution would be the best?
Here's maybe an example of what I'm looking for: http://www.emag.ro/
But any ideas of structures and codes would be much appreciated.
Keep in mind that I'll have to make it responsive as well.

Comment: Hi, @themarksmaker. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a targeted example of your code in a jsFiddle or otherwise. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask